# ons-list-item with dynamic height in onsen-ui

Tags: onsen-ui

I am developing an application which shows images in ons-list (each image in one ons-list-item)
Each image has different height, so I cannot set the height of the item to something fixed, as well as I cannot set the height of the ons-list-item to be dynamic. I've tried setting `overflow:auto` but i doesn't affect. Any Idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution in case of others having same question

setting display style on list-item as below

```
<ons-list-item style="display: table;"></ons-list-item>
```